# how to pinterest import for user post to wordpress automatically.?

Tags: wordpress, pinterest

I want to import pinterest post of specific url to wordpress application using specific url. like : [this link](https://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=puppies&term_meta[]=puppies%7Ctyped). I want to uses this posted data to our wordpress website.
So what should i do.? for showing this data to our website.

I have tried pinterest importer plugin but this plugin is asking for username password of particular user & i have used some pintrest developer api but not getting any solution.

Anybody help me.

please...

Answer (score 0):

i'm the [Pinterest Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pinterest-importer/) plugin's author.
I read your topic a while ago, and just updated it :
The v.0.4.0 now allows to import pins from other users.
Feel free to make a donation if you enjoy it !  Donation link is on the Wordpress page.